# How to browse added Service Reference content in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2015, I was able to easily browse through the added `Service References content` because they were visible in VS. All I needed to do was, click the little triangle next to Service Reference and it's content would expand.

**How do I do that in VS 2017? Or how do you work with Service References in VS 2017?**

**I need to see the autogenerated classes in file Reference.cs** and **now I use Resharper** to locate and open them, but it's a pain in the posterior do to that.

Comment: Hi Szymon. You have to uninstall VIsual Studio and install it once again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution explorer click on show all files.  Then expand the service reference to see reference.cs

[image]

Comment: Thank you :) Obvious things are hardest to notice. :)